warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3] Failed to determine the https port for redirect
I was trying to run my first Web API in ASP dotnet. The problem is that when I run the program
and open the: http://localhost:5074 the browser says:

This localhost page can’t be found

I tried to give certificate but did not also work.
I noticed that it is missing a https: port how can I solve this?
Please I need your experience 
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5074
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\Seth\DotNetPractice\ContosoPizza
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
      Failed to determine the https port for redirect.

Do I need to configure my launchSettings.json ?
What are the inadequacies with the launchSettings?

{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:32954",
      "sslPort": 443
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5074",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7297;http://localhost:5074",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}


you can add a https uri like https://localhost:7297;http://localhost:5074 (taken from json itself) in your launchsetting.json, there is already similar example in your json, Please check swagger launch setting in your json.

Great Idea!! I might as well try that..

It's expect behavior when you choose http like below.


If choose https option, then it will work with https.


Now you are facing `This localhost page can’t be found` 404 error.
Please follow my steps to check the issue.

Try to open the url http://localhost:5074/swagger in browser, check if we can see the swagger page.

Check the swagger settings in your Program.cs file.
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

If you change the RoutePrefix , the url of start page will be changed.

Check the environment variables , you can set breakpoint here.




The Issue still persist when I open http://localhost:5074 and https://localhost:7297,,
However when I open the url http://localhost:5074/swagger as you suggested it will work just fine..
I used studio visual code how to choose https when running?

@EmmanuelRusiana Try this https://github.com/webisora/vscode-liveserver-https.

@EmmanuelRusiana For more details, you can google it.

Thank you for giving me leads.. I'll look up to it :D
